# flask-user limit user registration

Tags: python, flask

I have a basic Flask app, using [Flask-User](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User), with templates and roles.

Defining roles and restricting access via decorators works nicely, however I'd like to limit access to the predefined function `user.register`. There's seem to be no pre-defined route, so using the decorator `@roles_required` seems incorrect.

I'm aware of how to restrict user registration completely (with
`USER_ENABLE_REGISTER = False`), but I'd like to have a special role, i.e. only an `Admin` user can register normal users.

Comment: You ever thought of setting users as inactive by default and then having the admin activate them. Gives similar effect

Comment: yes thanks! I've thought of something like this.. but this also isn't quite pretty.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Btw I was able to create a workaround in the register template. As you can access current_user.has_roles("Admin") and process it with jinja2..

However this seems to be quite ugly..

Best regards,
Nic.